# not getting the expected value when used location in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a login page using React.js. I'm using the useNavigate hook from react-router-dom to navigate to the homepage once the credentials are correct. In navigate hook I'm passing two parameters:

1. The homepage which I want to show once the credentials are correct.
2. The object with values which I want to use in the homepage.
   Below is the code of the loginForm

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import './login.css';
import { redirect } from "react-router-dom";
const LoginForm = () => {
    document.body.style = 'background:#20c997';
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [authenticated,setAuthenticated] = useState(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.getItem("authenticated") || false));
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleEmail = (e) => {
        setEmail(e.target.value);
    }
    const handlePassword = (e) => {
        setPassword(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const permEmail = "piyush@gmail.com";
        const permPass = "pass";
        if(email===permEmail && password===permPass){
            try{
                const param = {
                    stat:true
                };
                navigate("/loggedin",{
                    state:{
                        stat:true
                    }
                });
            }
            catch(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
            
        }else{
            window.alert("Wrong credentials");
        }
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div className="p-5">
                <div className="container text-start w-25 bg-light text-dark h-50 p-5 border border-primary border-2 rounded">
                    <form>
                        <div className="mb-3">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" className="form-label">Email address</label>
                            <input
                                type="email"
                                className="form-control border border-primary border-1"
                                id="exampleFormControlInput1"
                                placeholder="name@example.com"
                                onChange={(e) => handleEmail(e)}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="mb-3">
                            <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlInput2" className="form-label">Password</label>
                            <input
                                type="password"
                                className="form-control border border-primary border-1"
                                id="exampleFormControlInput2"
                                placeholder="password"
                                onChange={(e) => handlePassword(e)}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <button 
                        type="submit" 
                        className="btn btn-outline-primary border-1 mt-2"
                        onClick={e=>handleSubmit(e)}
                        >Submit</button>
                    </form>


                </div>
            </div>
        </>

    )
}

export default LoginForm;
```

Below is the homePage react code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const HomePage = () => {
    document.body.style = 'background:white';
    const location = useLocation();
    const [params,setParams] = useState([]);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        setData();
    }, [])
    async function setData(){
        setParams(JSON.stringify(location));
        console.log("location params:::"+params);
    }
    console.log("params:::"+params);
    console.log("params pathname:::"+params.pathname);

    if (params.pathname) {
        navigate("/login"); 
    }
    else {
        return (
            <>
                <h1>Hello world</h1>
            </>
        );
    }

}

export default HomePage;
```

Now in the homepage react code, I'm accessing this object using useLocation hook, and after setting the location data in the param state variable, I got the below object in the console.log

```
params:::{"pathname":"/loggedin","search":"","hash":"","state":{"stat":true},"key":"5na0qrwf"}
```

but the value of params.pathname is undefined

```
params pathname:::undefined
```

Can anyone please explain, why this is happening

Comment: Because `params` is a string, not an object. You converted it to string here: `setParams(JSON.stringify(location))`

Comment: Ohh Okay.... But If I don't do that then I will get [object object] as an output in console. How can we deal with this?